# PowerBi Map Interactions

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 maps in PowerBi, one shows a job count and the other a material spend. If I zoom one map to look at a problem area I want the other maps to zoom to that point too. I cant find any mention of how this could be done but wondering if anyone knows?

[PowerBi Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knmfg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do would be to add a Slicer based on "area", which would apply to both maps.